# Is it possible to use Bootstrap Bias-corrected confidence intervals when performing SEM?

Tags: bootstrap, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor

As far as I know, Co-variance based SEM requires the normality assumption. To avoid violating this assumption, I am considering using Bootstrap Bias-corrected method intervals for hypothesis testing when performing CB-SEM in AMOS. However, I have found not many studies using these two methods combined. I think the main reason is that the authors tend to perform CFA before using SEM and all the indicators in their studies do not violate the threshold values, but this is my first research paper and I have not had enough foundation in Statistics so I am not sure.
Is it possible to use Bootstrap Bias-corrected confidence intervals when performing CB-SEM model for hypothesis testing? If yes, is there anything I should perform before doing CB-SEM combined with Bootstrapping? To provide more context: My CFA indicators are fine.

Comment: bias-corrected bootstrap CIs are a standard feature in other SEM software (M*plus*, `lavaan`).  If you look for simulation studies on mediation models (e.g., MacKinnon, Preacher, Hayes, Montoya, and others), you should find some investigations on their use in SEM.  But the method requires raw data.  Alternatively, if you only have access to summary statistics, then indeed you are stuck assuming normality (unless you use ULS estimation), and the only bootstrap available is the parametric bootstrap, called a "Monte Carlo CI" in this context: https://doi.org/10.1080/19312458.2012.679848